# SQL Server : Cursor performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, cursor

I am using cursor in a stored procedure and there is no other way but the cursor.

I have pasted my script here. I want to improve the performance of this cursor.
A little background. Im passing 'name' and 'action' and cursor is calling different stored procedures in return. I have passed another parameter (ID) in all of those stored procedures. Please improve the performance.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Driver_sp
AS

TRUNCATE TABLE Driver_tbl

INSERT INTO Driver_tbl (ID,Name,Action,vipbatchid,processseq)
SELECT ID,Name,Action,batchid,ProcessSeq
FROM pcis_tbl


DECLARE @name varchar(20),
        @action varchar(20),
        @ID bigint

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT id,name,action FROM Driver_tbl
    ORDER BY processseq

OPEN cur  

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @id, @name,@action

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

   if (@name = 'A' and @action = 'Update')  
   BEGIN exec A_sp @ID END 
     else 
     if (@name = 'B' and @action = 'Update') 
     BEGIN exec B_sp @ID END 
       else
       if (@name = 'C' and @action = 'Update')
       BEGIN exec C_sp @ID END 
         else 
         if (@name = 'D' and @action = 'Update') 
         BEGIN exec D_sp @ID END 


fetch next FROM cur INTO @id, @name,@action

END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Thanks !!

Comment: "*there is no other way but the cursor*" I reject your assessment.

Comment: If you make those stored procs user defined functions, you won't need an explicit cursor.

Comment: Or rewrite to one proc that handles the cases in a set-based fashion. This could include using an input variable of the table type if you aer on SQL Server 2008. Remember code reuse takes a distant second to performance in a database.

Comment: Not knowing what the procs do, it is hard to adequately help you improve performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming, you're using TSQL, change CURSOR declaration to

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
```